# Duplicado de información al consultar API hecha en php

Tags: php, mysql, api

Hice una pequenña api en php:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    include_once'conexion.php';
    $cliente_usu = $_GET['cliente_usuario'];
    $cliente_pass = $_GET['cliente_pass'];
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'GET')
    {

        $consulta_buscar_usuario = 'SELECT * FROM api_usuario WHERE usuario_nombre = ? AND usuario_contrasena = ?';
        $ejecutar_cbu = $pdo->prepare($consulta_buscar_usuario);
        $ejecutar_cbu->execute(array($cliente_usu,$cliente_pass));
        $data_respuesta = $ejecutar_cbu->fetch();
    }
    echo json_encode($data_respuesta);
?>
```

que recibe un usuario y contraseña y devuelve un json, el problema es que repite la información
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo debería devolver lo que está dentro del recuadro rojo, uso un servidor local apache y una base de datos mysql con la que se conecta correctamente, para consumir la api utilizo la siguiente línea: http://localhost/api/datos.php?cliente_usuario=admin&cliente_pass=admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te devuelve tanto los indices numericos como los indices asociativos puesto que ese es el comportamiento normal de fetch si no se le especifican parametros, pero si deseas solo obtener los campos que no sean numericos (campos asociativos), puedes hacer uso de una constante estatica de `PDO` llamada `FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
$data_respuesta = $ejecutar_cbu->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Eso resolvera el inconveniente.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, funciona.